# Apply sum product on columns of a dataframe in rolling windows

Tags: r, moving-average, quantitative-finance, weighted-average, rolling-computation

I have a set of defined weights and I want to calculate the weighted sum of returns in rolling windows on a time series dataframe. I believe we would use `rollapplyr` here, but I am unsure how to perform rolling window function across each row of the dataframe.

Find below dput output of a sample of the data:

```
tempVar <- structure(c(NA, -0.0081833512947922, 0.00508150903899551, -0.0072202479734873, 
0.00345258369231161, NA, 0, -0.00847462699097257, -0.00794638265247283, 
0.00445091892889238, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0, -0.0136462286616492, 
-0.00638979809877149, -0.00109950533341685), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(946598400, 
946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 947116800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("TY00.USA", "CGB00.MOD", "G10L00.IFEU", "RLI00.IFEU"
    )))
```

And simplicity, lets consider weights to be:

```
tempWeights <- c(1.09,0.89,0)
```

Note: the weights suggest that as of the date of evaluation, returns of that date have no weighting.These weights do not sum to 1 by design

I would like the output to be:

```
tempRRI <- structure(c(NA, NA, NA, -0.00439731, -0.0008871759, NA, NA, NA, 
-0.00754241803, -0.0163096243, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
-0.01214514381, -0.02056130983), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("TY00.USA", "CGB00.MOD", "G10L00.IFEU", "RLI00.IFEU"
    )), index = structure(c(946598400, 946857600, 946944000, 
947030400, 947116800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexTZ = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC")
```

Hopefully something similar to `weighted.mean()` but for sum, or if someone can please advise how I can can take sum product of each column (on rolling basis) with `tempWeights`.The `weighted.sum()` does not do the same thing.

```
tempRRI <- rollapplyr(tempVar, width = 3, function(x) {weighted.mean(x,tempWeights)}, by.column = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you explain the calculation for 1-2 value ? How is it calculated ?

Comment: I believe you are referring to `tempRRI`: for every j, `tempVar[i,j] = (tempVar[i-2,j]*1.09) + (tempVar[i-1,j]*0.89)  + (tempVar[i,j]*0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You adjust the formula by multiplying weighted.mean() with the sum of weights:

```
tempRRI <- rollapplyr(tempVar, width = 3, function(x) {weighted.mean(x,tempWeights)*sum(tempWeights)}, by.column = TRUE)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24763721)

Comment: @Beppe - I have posted here the answer to my own (i.e. author's) question