# Fill NAs in a time series for specific number of dates only

Tags: r, time-series, na, xts, quantitative-finance

Is there a way to fill NAs in xts object, but only upto a month forward? My time series is on a weekday frequency. I want to avoid backward filling data at a particular date with a value that is more than a month old. #note: no of weekdays in the month vary and therefore, I don't have a fixed number to set as input for `maxgap` in `na.locf`. Plus, `maxgap =20` did not work for me on the below sample set for column `Z`.

Small excerpt of the dataset:

```
tempY <- structure(c(1.013367062565, 1.02549265039, 1.06441613562, 1.061125834671, 
1.058095154587, 1.019989589422, 1.009980314126, 1.020806729739, 
1.026513004385, 1.025998357485, 1.011398006146, NA, 1.014043343859, 
1.016744497778, 1.027453095813, 1.030421507552, 1.059024397083, 
1.050921074032, 1.054401954388, 1.05940756622, 1.088564123549, 
1.063802687358, 1.047656980939, 1.051924103152, 1.038016436332, 
1.038100571345, 1.037565907689, 1.024397906272, 1.04517232233, 
1.040964696607, 1.085927457557, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.141623602982, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.044212, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(946598400, 
946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 
947548800, 947635200, 947721600, 947808000, 948067200, 948153600, 
948240000, 948326400, 948412800, 948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 
948931200, 949017600, 949276800, 949363200, 949449600, 949536000, 
949622400, 949881600, 949968000, 950054400, 950140800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(30L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y", "Z")))
```

Expected output:

```
tempZ <- structure(c(1.013367062565, 1.02549265039, 1.06441613562, 1.061125834671, 
1.058095154587, 1.019989589422, 1.009980314126, 1.020806729739, 
1.026513004385, 1.025998357485, 1.011398006146, 1.011398006146, 
1.014043343859, 1.016744497778, 1.027453095813, 1.030421507552, 
1.059024397083, 1.050921074032, 1.054401954388, 1.05940756622, 
1.088564123549, 1.063802687358, 1.047656980939, 1.051924103152, 
1.038016436332, 1.038100571345, 1.037565907689, 1.024397906272, 
1.04517232233, 1.040964696607, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.141623602982, 
1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 
1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 
1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 
1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 
1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 1.044212, 
1.044212, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("xts", "zoo"
), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(946598400, 
946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 
947548800, 947635200, 947721600, 947808000, 948067200, 948153600, 
948240000, 948326400, 948412800, 948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 
948931200, 949017600, 949276800, 949363200, 949449600, 949536000, 
949622400, 949881600, 949968000, 950054400, 950140800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(30L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y", "Z")))
```

Update: @G. Grothendieck: dput output for one variable:

````
structure(c(1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 1.085927457557, 
1.085927457557, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 
1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 
1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 
1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 
1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 
1.141623602982, 1.141623602982, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 
1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 
1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 
1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 
1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 
1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, 1.181744131387, NA, NA, 1.113811336182, 
1.113811336182, 1.113811336182, 1.113811336182, 1.113811336182
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(946598400, 
946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400, 
947548800, 947635200, 947721600, 947808000, 948067200, 948153600, 
948240000, 948326400, 948412800, 948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 
948931200, 949017600, 949276800, 949363200, 949449600, 949536000, 
949622400, 949881600, 949968000, 950054400, 950140800, 950227200, 
950486400, 950572800, 950659200, 950745600, 950832000, 951091200, 
951177600, 951264000, 951350400, 951436800, 951696000, 951782400, 
951868800, 951955200, 952041600, 952300800, 952387200, 952473600, 
952560000, 952646400, 952905600, 952992000, 953078400, 953164800, 
953251200, 953510400, 953596800, 953683200, 953769600, 953856000, 
954115200, 954201600, 954288000, 954374400, 954460800, 954720000, 
954806400, 954892800, 954979200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(70L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "X990100"))```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rollapplyr` in zoo can take a vector width.  We can set each of its elements to be the number of points from the current point to a month ago (i.e. the current position minus the position a month ago) and then `rollapplyr` can apply `na.locf0` to only the last month.

```
library(lubridate)
library(xts)

tt <- time(tempY)
w <- seq_along(tt) - findInterval(tt %m-% months(1), tt)
Fill <- function(x) {
  last <- tail(x, 1)
  if (is.na(last)) tail(na.locf0(x), 1) else last
}

rollapplyr(as.zoo(tempY), w, Fill)
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks! By the way, can I be cheeky and ask you to have a look at another rolling window problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59103221/apply-sum-product-on-columns-of-a-dataframe-in-rolling-windows?noredirect=1#comment104438758_59103221] Thanks!!

Comment: Looking at the output, can you advise how I can change this to sometimes accommodate for 1month +2 days. If you review the dput (now included in my question above), you'd notice that the last working day in Feb 2000 is the 28th and hence the value is carried forward only upto 28 Mar 2000 as against the 30th Mar 2000. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question or the context of the output.  If x is a date class vector, e.g. `x <- Sys.Date() - (1:0)` then `x-2` is two days before each component and `as.Date(as.yearmon(x) - 1/12, frac = 1) - 2` is two days before the end of the prior month.  Is that what you are asking?  Neither of these use lubridate.

Comment: Thank you for your time on reviewing this. I am working on financial data, to add a bit of context. The dataset is lists financial prices on each weekday for a certain time period. As a result, last value for some months would be on a date prior to last date of the month. Also, some month have fewer days in a month than following months (eg Feb 2000). While you code works for most dates, in falters on specific dates which appear in one month, but don't in the previous. Taking the example of Feb 2000, last data point is on 28th. ...

Comment: As a result, I am unable to use na.locf to fill NAs for dates 29th-31st March 2000. How can I tinker the code to allow flexibility of stretching a couple of days beyond precise 1 month in such cases. I tried `w <- seq_along(tt) - findInterval(tt %m-% months(1) - 2, tt)`. But this can affect NA backfills on 1st of a month. For example, if NA on 01 March 2000, if last value is on 31 Jan 2000 but not after; I do not want 31 Jan 2000 to be used for replacing NA.